# Perl DBI module do not raise exception

Tags: mysql, windows, dbi, perl

I try to run some statement, which will fail, in `do()` method with DBI `RaiseError` flag is ON, but it doesn`t raise an exception.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test;host=192.168.10.101",
                        "test", "123456", {'RaiseError' => 1});

eval { $dbh->do("DROP TABLE foo") }; # foo table not exist
if ($@) {
    print "Dropping foo failed: $@\n";
} else {
    print "ok\n";
}
```

This code return `ok` instead error.

I have this problem only on Windows 7 machine. (When I run this code on Linux exception is raised.) Is it a bug?

Perl version: 5.16.3,
DBI version: 1.623,
DBD::mysql version: 4.022

Comment: It raises the exception, but you catch it and throw it away, by using `eval { ... }`. Aaah, that's actually what you want to do. Does the error appear when you remove the `eval { ... }`? Then maybe try `my $run_ok = eval { $dbh->do("DROP TABLE foo");1 }; my $err = $@; if( ! $run_ok ) { warn "<<$err>>" }`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the issue, but don't test `$@` to see if an exception occurred, make the eval return a true value and test its return value. See https://mvp.kablamo.org/essentials/die-eval/ or try the more intuitive try/catch syntax https://mvp.kablamo.org/essentials/try-catch/

Answer (score 0):

Updating DBD::mysql to the latest version has helped me.